# Error when i use impdp for restore from backup in oracle

Tags: oracle, restore

```
expdp backupuser/a123A123a123@//localhost:1521/ORCLPDB1 DIRECTORY=EXP NETWORK_LINK=EXP_TEST DUMPFILE=EXP131066.DMP LOGFILE=EXP131066.LOG TABLES=EMP
```

I use this command to take backup from remote oracle host and it successfully completed and I test that everything is ok.

```
impdp backupuser/a123A123a123@//localhost:1521/ORCLPDB1 DIRECTORY=EXP NETWORK_LINK=EXP_TEST DUMPFILE=EXP131066.DMP LOGFILE=EXP131067.LOG
```

When I use this command to restore my backup to source database that I was take backup from that I get this error:

```
Import: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Jun 14 13:19:49 2022
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 21c Enterprise Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
ORA-39006: internal error
ORA-39068: invalid master table data in row with PROCESS_ORDER=-2
ORA-00904: "SYS"."KUPU$UTILITIES"."GET_PLATFORM_NAME": invalid identifier

ORA-39097: Data Pump job encountered unexpected error -904
```

What should I do?

Comment: Can you update the question with the version of the remote DB? is it the same one used for expdp and impdp?

Comment: My target database that I remote to source database is version 21 and my source database is 19.
I don't think it was from that because I take backup successfully with network_link and when I want to restore that backup from target database with network_link I get this error.
When I copy my backup to source database server then I can restore that locally successfully .

Answer (score 2):

**PLEASE** STOP calling these things **Backups**!!
They're not.

expdp and impdp are Data Transfer tools, ***not*** Recovery tools.

To backup any Oracle database, you MUST use RMAN (if only for the sake of your sanity and any realistic expectation of keeping your job).

According to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-BAA3B679-A758-4D55-9820-432D9EB83C68.htm#SUTIL110) pushing the data "uphill", into a newer version of Oracle, should "just work".
I think what you're falling foul of here is going the other way, back "downhill" to an older version.
For that, expdp & impdp have the VERSION parameter, with which you can specify the version of the *destination* database.